# getting error in shell script when run with sh

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, runtime-error

I have made one script  and I tried to ran with the below syntax

```
sh <script_name>
```

it gave me errors
and when I ran the same script

```
./<script_name>
```

it executed successfully.

not found where the issue is?

Comment: what's the error? what's the script?

Comment: You can run sh scripts with `sh`, just like you can run Python scripts with `python` and Bash scripts with `bash`. If you try to run a bash script or python script with `sh`, it will fail. `./yourscript` will run the interpreter the script says it needs, so it will always work if the script's shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) is correct

Comment: To clarify what @thatotherguy said: your script is probably a bash script that uses bashisms (eg, syntax that is not recognized by classic `sh`) and your `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Sorry i don't have screen shot now.

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you  . It is helpful answer

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you